# Login using "pre Windows 2000" username to Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Is it possible to login to Active Directory using the `pre Windows 2000` username to Active Directory using Unboundid ldap sdk?
The `pre Windows 2000` username is `DOMAIN\username` and an end user may enter it in the login page.

If yes, how is possible to do it?

Is `pre Windows 2000` username LDAPv3 compliant?

*Added*

For successful authentication I need to find a user DN user using provided user information.
Unfortunately, there is no such attribute as `DOMAIN` in Active Directory (and probably in other LDAPs also).
The domain is part of UPN – but I want to perform the standard LDAP search using the object attributes.
How is possible to find a user object using `DOMAIN\username`?

Comment: Why don't you simply do on after 13 years and use UPNs?

Comment: Thanks, it is legacy customers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SDK is implemented correctly, it should not care how the bind username looks like because it will simply pass the string to the directory. It can be a DN, Legacy Logon Name, Implicit or Explicit User Principal Name, maybe even a SID. Can't you simply try it out?

Comment: Yes, I did it without success.
For successful authentication I need to find a user DN user using provided user information.
Unfortunately, there is no such attribute as `DOMAIN` in Active Directory.
The domain is part of UPN – but I want to perform the standard LDAP search using the object attributes.
How is possible to find a user object using `DOMAIN\username`?

Comment: Please provide the exact error returned by the Active Directory. Use Wireshark if you need to and will see exactly why your bind fails. You can translate the realm to the netbios domain, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14119753/696632). I have fully functioning code how to find the DN of a user in forest based on the UPN, you'd simply nead to translate the Legacy Logon Name to a UPN.

Comment: Do you know if `DOMAIN\username` is LDAPv3 compliant?

Comment: Read [here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4513#page-15). The RFC requires a DN but the Active Directory is more flexible, it supports several formats, and yes it support the legacy names too, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it is only Active Directory supports several formats and the `DOMAIN\username` will not work for other vendors.

Comment: @Michael, correct. Did you try again and read the error message?

Comment: I decided not to support it since it is not LDAPv3 compliant. I promote and accept your answer for your help in comments.

Comment: @Michael, what do you use instead? No user will memorize his DN.

Comment: Correct, to find DN I perform search using for user using `sAMAccountName` and `userPrincipalName` attributes.
As I stated before, I can not search for the domain since LDAP do not support it.